# Looking for a rspec matcher that checks a value to be included in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

How can I write this:

> Given an array `b = ['one', 'two', 'three']`
>
> I expect value `a` to be
>   included in the array `b`.

I want to use it together with an `all` matcher so my final code would look like this:

```
b = ['one', 'two', 'three']
my_list = [ {'type' => 'one'}, {'type' => 'two'}, {'type' => 'three'} ]
expect(my_list).to all(include("type" => a_value_included_in(b))
```

Which is testing for:

> all hashes from `my_list` must have a `type` key whose value is in array `b`.

Is there such built-in matcher in Rspec?

And how do you check inclusion of a value in the array besides using the obvious reverse: `expect([1, 2, 3]).to include(value)`, which in my example, is not really fitting in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check if **every** string from `b` is present in any of the hashes from `my_list`:

```
b = ['one', 'two', 'three']
my_list = [ {'type' => 'one'}, {'type' => 'two'}, {'type' => 'three'} ]
b.each do |str|
  expect(my_list.find { |h| h['type'] == str }).to be_present
end
```

Or, you can go with:

```
expect(my_list.map { |h| h['type'] }.sort) to eq(b.sort)
```

> So when someone adds `my_list << { 'type' => 'not_in_list' }` the spec
>   will fail.

```
expect(my_list.map { |h| b.include?(h['type']) }.uniq).to eq(true)
```

Comment: My use case is testing that all hashes from my_list must have a `type` key whose value is in array `b`. I think your suggestion sounds like it's testing for something else.

Comment: @Cristian it's impossible, because hash can only contain uniq keys, so it is technically not possible to have a hash with more, than single value at given key. if you want to check whether all hashes from `my_list` contain `type` key and it's value is an array, you can do: `expect(my_list.all? { |h| h['type'].sort == b.sort }).to eq(true)`

Comment: no, the value at key `type` is always a string, and I want to ensure that the strings are in a predefined array (kind of like how `enum` works). So when someone adds `my_list << { 'type' => 'not_in_list' }` the spec will fail.

Comment: @Cristian oh, it's an easy one, just map `my_list`s hashes by value at `type` and check whether `b` always includes this value. Edited the answer

Comment: All right, I guess this is the only way. I was hoping to be able to use a matcher for nicer syntax. Can I change the last solution to: `expect(my_list.all? { |h| b.include?(h['type']) }).to be(true)` (a bit cleaner)

Comment: @Cristian this are nested checks, nothing like this is inbuilt, yet :) Yea, your version is cleaner indeed and looks to be doing exact same thing

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would simply use (order of elements doesn't matter):

```
expect(my_list).to match_array(b.map{|v| { 'type' =>  v })
```

or use `include` matcher instead of `match_array` if `b` can ba accepted as a subset of `my_list`.

I don't think that special matcher for such cases exists and/or it's really needed. Still, you can create a custom one if you really can't live w/o it.